# LiftOver in R (error)

Tags: r, apply, data-conversion, bioconductor, genome

I am trying to use the LiftOver function in `rtracklayer` package but I am getting one error, this is my code:

```
library(rtracklayer)
library(gwascat)
library(IRanges)

chain <- import.chain("bosTau6.hg19.all.chain")

df <- read.table(textConnection("chr  start  end
chr5  58024309  58039917"), header =T)

library(GenomicRanges)

gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df, TRUE)

humcon <- liftOver(gr, chain)
```

To download and extract the chain file into work folder I used:

```
wget http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/bosTau6/vsHg19/bosTau6.hg19.all.chain.gz
gunzip gunzip bosTau6.hg19.all.chain.gz
```

The error follows:

```
Warning message:
'mseqapply' is deprecated.
Use 'as(mapply(FUN, ...), 'List')' instead.
See help("Deprecated")
```

Some ideas why it is not working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a warning, not an error.

A simple web search found:

https://www.biostars.org/p/122005/